# how can I navigate through an array, check all the elements between them and if they meet a criteria display them?

Tags: java

Okay so the problem is simple but I don't understand how to do it. I tried to check 2 elements, one by one but this isnt the best way. I have an array of Circle objects. The array has position fields, X and Y. I want to go through the array and check all the elements if they are on a line(horizontal or vertical). How can I go through the array and check if the center of the circles are on the same line.

I tried to do something like this to see if the circles are on the same vertical line but how I said it takes one element with the neighbour.

```
void isCenterSameHorizOrVert(Circle[] c) {
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < c.length - 1; j++) {
            if(c[i].getPlanarX() == c[j].getPlanarX()) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method will probably want to return a boolean for a start.

Comment: If the circles are on the same line vertically? Then will the centers just have the same y value or x value?

Comment: What does getPlanarX() return?

Comment: @Ammar i assume x coord

Comment: So only if all of the Circles are on the same line will it show? And do they have to all be on the vertical OR all be on the horizontal. Otherwise can some be aligned on the horizontal while others vertical and still show?

Comment: Oh let me just post the problem here. Sorry for late answer.

Comment: Implement a class named Circle with the private attributes color (int), radius (float), planar position (2 integer). Define
the specific constructors and setter getter methods. The color is divided in 4 bytes, each of them representing the
transparency and the quantities of R, G and B.
In the main method (included in another class), read from the keyboard the data for n Circle objects.
Implement the methods that receive as parameter the array of objects and display.

Comment: - the circles whose center is included in one of the 4 quadrants
- the circles that are included entirely in one of the 4 quadrants
- the circles that have the centers on the same horizontal or vertical line
- the circles that have the R, G or B quantities in a certain specified interval

Comment: So I need help with the third method - the circles that have the centers on the same horizontal or vertical line .

Comment: Ok so what confuses me about that question is: say you have 3 circles. One circle is in the center. The next is to the left (in a line), and the last is above (in a line). The third circle aligns with the first. The second aligns with the first. But the second does not align with the third. So do they ALL have to align vertical or ALL have to align horizontal. Or do they ALL have to align vertical/horizontal with at least one other? Hope this makes sense what im asking.

Comment: Display the circles that aligns and on which cord: for ex circle 1 aligns circle 2 on x, circle 1 aligns circle 3 on y

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
package amedv;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

class Circle {
    int positionX;
    int positionY;

    public Circle(int positionX, int positionY) {
        super();
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }
    public int getPositionX() {
        return positionX;
    }
    public void setPositionX(int positionX) {
        this.positionX = positionX;
    }
    public int getPositionY() {
        return positionY;
    }
    public void setPositionY(int positionY) {
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }
}

class CircleHM {
    HashMap hmCirlesX;
    HashMap hmCirlesY;

    public HashMap getHmCirlesX() {
        return hmCirlesX;
    }
    public void setHmCirlesX(HashMap hmCirlesX) {
        this.hmCirlesX = hmCirlesX;
    }
    public HashMap getHmCirlesY() {
        return hmCirlesY;
    }
    public void setHmCirlesY(HashMap hmCirlesY) {
        this.hmCirlesY = hmCirlesY;
    }

}

public class CircleTest {

    private Circle[] circles = new Circle[] {new Circle(1,2), new Circle(1,5), new Circle(6,7), new Circle(2,7), new Circle(3,8), new Circle(3,5)};

    private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> hmCirlesX = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>();
    private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> hmCirlesY = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>();

    private boolean findCircleWithCenterSameHorizOrVert(Circle[] cirArr) {
        if (cirArr.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        int hashCode = cirArr.hashCode();

        if (!hmCirlesX.containsKey(hashCode) && !hmCirlesY.containsKey(hashCode)) {
            hmCirlesX.put(hashCode, new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>());
            hmCirlesY.put(hashCode, new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>());
        for (int i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {      
            ArrayList arrlCirclesX = hmCirlesX.get(hashCode).containsKey(circles[i].positionX) ? hmCirlesX.get(hashCode).get(circles[i].positionX) : new ArrayList();
            arrlCirclesX.add(circles[i]);
            hmCirlesX.get(hashCode).put(circles[i].positionX, arrlCirclesX);

            ArrayList arrlCirclesY = hmCirlesY.get(hashCode).containsKey(circles[i].positionY) ? hmCirlesY.get(hashCode).get(circles[i].positionY) : new ArrayList();
            arrlCirclesY.add(circles[i]);
            hmCirlesY.get(hashCode).put(circles[i].positionY, arrlCirclesY);
        }
        }

        return (hmCirlesX.size() > 0 && hmCirlesY.size() > 0);      
    }

    private void showCenterSameHorizOrVert(Circle[] cirArr) {
        if (findCircleWithCenterSameHorizOrVert(cirArr)) {
            int hashCode = cirArr.hashCode();

            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hmX = hmCirlesX.get(hashCode);
            HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hmY = hmCirlesY.get(hashCode);

            Iterator itmX = hmX.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itmX.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry hmArrListX = (Map.Entry)itmX.next();
            ArrayList cirX = (ArrayList) hmArrListX.getValue();
            System.out.println("Circles on the same X = " + hmArrListX.getKey());
            for (int i=0; i < cirX.size(); i++) {
                Circle c = (Circle) cirX.get(i);
              System.out.println("c.positionX = " + c.positionX + " c.positionY = " + c.positionY);         
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        Iterator itmY = hmY.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itmY.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry hmArrListY = (Map.Entry)itmY.next();
            ArrayList cirY = (ArrayList) hmArrListY.getValue();
            System.out.println("Circles on the same Y = " + hmArrListY.getKey());
            for (int i=0; i < cirY.size(); i++) {
                Circle c = (Circle) cirY.get(i);
              System.out.println("c.positionX = " + c.positionX + " c.positionY = " + c.positionY);         
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("circles.length = " + circles.length);
        System.out.println("");
        showCenterSameHorizOrVert(circles);
    }

}
```

It will give me result:

```
circles.length = 6

Circles on the same X = 1
c.positionX = 1 c.positionY = 2
c.positionX = 1 c.positionY = 5

Circles on the same X = 2
c.positionX = 2 c.positionY = 7

Circles on the same X = 3
c.positionX = 3 c.positionY = 8
c.positionX = 3 c.positionY = 5

Circles on the same X = 6
c.positionX = 6 c.positionY = 7



Circles on the same Y = 2
c.positionX = 1 c.positionY = 2

Circles on the same Y = 5
c.positionX = 1 c.positionY = 5
c.positionX = 3 c.positionY = 5

Circles on the same Y = 7
c.positionX = 6 c.positionY = 7
c.positionX = 2 c.positionY = 7

Circles on the same Y = 8
c.positionX = 3 c.positionY = 8
```

I used Integer for X and Y to simplify printout, may me you need to replace it to Double.
I store result in HashMap based on array hashcode to not loop each time you run this function the whole array and inside it loop whole array only once and put all values in two HashMaps based on X and Y coordinates (its group all values based on this keys) and then I just loop resulted HashMaps with groupped values to show which objects on the same line based on X or Y. Hope my logic will help you adjust it to your needs.